# count number of columns with the same name R

Tags: r, dataframe, count, col

I have a big data frame that in its short version looks like this:

```
> test
  SRA_Ucon SRA_Uinc SRA_Ucon.1 MID_Rinc MID_Rinc.1 SRA_Ucon.2 MID_cueR MID_Rinc.2 Neut_con Neut_con.1
1        0        0          0        0          0          0        0          0        0          0
2        0        0          0        0          0          0        0          0        0          0
```

I want to count the number of columns that start with the same name. For example, in this case, I would like to count number of **SRA_Ucon** columns. There are three of them here. So, I would like to get an output of number "3". What is the optimal way of doing it?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Use `gsub` to remove the periods followed by a number. Then use `table`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use grep on the column names and check the length of the response.

```
 length(grep(x = colnames(test), pattern = "^SRA_Ucon"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `substring` with `==`

```
sum(substring(colnames(test), 1, 8)== "SRA_Ucon")
#[1] 3
```